# Is WinAppDriver works only with the applications which are installed on Windows10?

Tags: winappdriver

Is WinAppDriver works only with the applications which are installed on Windows10 machine?  I need to Automate the installation process of a software, but WinAppDriver simply does not find the elements on the installation wizard.

I am giving capability "app" = "Path till Setup.exe", WinAppDriver launched the installation wizard but fails to locate the "Next" button on the wizard.

Comment: The document itself they are clearly mentioned "This service supports testing on Windows 10 PCs."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, WinAppDriver is supported on machines running Windows 10 (Home and Pro) and Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , The document itself they are clearly mentioned "This service supports testing Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and Classic Windows (Win32) apps on **Windows 10 PCs** ".

Go through this document [WinAppDriver Document](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver#windows-application-driver)

Answer (score 0):

WinAppDriver tests can only be developed on Windows 10 or MS Server 2016. Once developed, those tests can run on earlier versions of windows. See [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/UI-Tests-for-Desktop-and-UWP-Apps#c636759055350948681) at 31:30.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Docs/FAQ.md

> **What are the system requirements for WinAppDriver?**
>
> WinAppDriver is supported on machines running W**indows 10 (Home and
> Pro)** and **Windows Server 2016**.